# How to set OUT parameter in PROCEDURE

Tags: phpmyadmin

I use phpMyAdmin version 4.1.14.8 and MySQL version 5.5

I have a procedure that does exactly what I want. I created it with the procedure popup-dialog in phpMyAdmin.

Now when I call it I just want to know if he created the entry or not.

Procedure is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
`entries`
(`user_id`, `creationDate`, `description`)
SELECT
`user`.`id`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, description
FROM
`user`
WHERE
`user`.`session_id` != ''
AND
`user`.`session_id` = session_id
```

Now I wanted to set the newly created id as an OUT parameter with LAST_INSERT_ID() but I am unsure how to do this because whenever is use a semicolon to finish the first statement and just adding e.g.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`entries`;
```

phpMyAdmin throws an error saying I should read the manual on how to do the whole part after the first semicolon =(

Comment: Add the complete and literal error that phpMyAdmin throws to you. It have clues to know what happens

Comment: Die folgende Abfrage ist fehlgeschlagen: "CREATE DEFINER=``@`` PROCEDURE `createUser`(IN `username` VARCHAR(150) CHARSET utf8, IN `email` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8, IN `pw` VARCHAR(100) CHARSET utf8) NOT DETERMINISTIC MODIFIES SQL DATA SQL SECURITY DEFINER INSERT INTO  `user`  (`username`, `email`, `password`) VALUES  (username, email, pw); SELECT  * FROM  `user`;"

Comment: MySQL meldet: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT  * FROM  `user`' at line 6

Comment: As you see, he seems to have a problem with 2 statements in one procedure. If I execute them seperatly or even in the "execute sql" tab of phpmyadmin everything is cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem here was that I assumed that phpMyAdmin would already add `BEGIN` and `END` to the procedure...